# search for data LIKE a variable but i want to find data like %?% but of course this doesn't work

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-like

Im trying to search for data LIKE a variable but i want to find data like %?% but of course this doesn't work i can use LIKE ? but i need to also find all values with e.g D and comes up with Dog

```
       search=self.text
    with sqlite3.connect('Data.db') as db:
        user_find = db.cursor()
        user_find.execute(
            'select * from "Animal Data" where Animal_ID LIKE ? or Animal_Name LIKE ? or Animal_Type LIKE ? or Animal_Gender LIKE ? or Animal_breed LIKE ? or Animal_breed LIKE ? or Animal_breed LIKE? or Animal_colour LIKE ? or Address LIKE ?'
            ,(search,search,search,search,search,search,search,search,search,))
        data = user_find.fetchall()
        print(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be binding to the `?` placeholder the entire expression you want to appear in the `LIKE` statement.  That is, if you wanted to search for any field having the letter `D`, you would bind the string `%D%` to your statement.

```
search = '%' + search + '%'
user_find = db.cursor()
user_find.execute(
    'select * from "Animal Data" where Animal_ID LIKE ? or Animal_Name LIKE ? or Animal_Type LIKE ? or Animal_Gender LIKE ? or Animal_breed LIKE ? or Animal_breed LIKE ? or Animal_breed LIKE? or Animal_colour LIKE ? or Address LIKE ?',
    (search,search,search,search,search,search,search,search,search,)
)
data = user_find.fetchall()
print(data)
```

Comment: wow thanks for the quick reply yeah that makes complete sense thanks a lot